# JQuery unrecognized expression [href=#undefined]

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I just upgraded wordpress on my site to `v4.5.1` however since doing this some functionality on my site has broken....

When I view the console I see this message:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#undefined]
```

I'm completely at a loss as to where to look to fix this issue... would anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue? I've checked and I'm running `jQuery 1.12.3` as this comes packed with Wordpress.

Upon further inspection I think the error is being thrown from within the below function... I can't seem to fix it though, any ideas?

```
  currentScrollIndication: function () {
    var e = 0;
    j.hasClass("sticky-header-enabled") && (e = jQuery(".header-wrap").height());
    var t = jQuery(".blank_spacer:in-viewport:first").attr("id"), 
        a = jQuery("#main-navigation .menu li a"), 
        i = a.filter("[href=#" + t + "]");
    a.parent().removeClass("current-scroll-item"), 
    i.length > 0 && !i.hasClass(".current-scroll-item") && (a.parent().removeClass("current-scroll-item"), 
    i.parent().addClass("current-scroll-item"))
}
```

Comment: Waypoints is it? Try with: `i = a.filter('[href="#' + t + '"]');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `#undefined` is not a valid CSS identifier, you cannot use it bare like that.

Instead, you need `[href='#undefined']`, which means your JS code is:

```
i = a.filter("[href='#"+t+"']");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! Seriously appreciate that :) Can i just ask why this happened as a result of updating to jquery 1.12 though? As this problem was never present on my site?

Comment: Older versions of jQuery may not have used `querySelectorAll` when browsers support it, or have other updates to the parser that made it more strict.